# Display the values of two arrays and save it in the database using foreach in Mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

I have two arrays, the array that holds the child name and the other one is an array that holds the birthday of the child. 
This is the design of my form that the user will fill up. 
[image]

```html
<div id="Children">
  <div class="form-group col-md-7">
    <label for="child">Name of Child</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="child[]" id="child" placeholder="FULL NAME">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="ch_DateOfBirth">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" name="ch_DateOfBirth[]" id="DateOfBirth" placeholder="Date of Birth">

  </div>
```

and this is my php code for saving the two arrays in the database.

```html
$child_name=$_POST['child'];
$child_bday=date('Y-d-m', strtotime($_POST['ch_DateOfBirth']));
$count=count($child_name);

for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) { 
  $sql6="INSERT into  tbl_children (Emp_ID, Ch_Name, Ch_Bdate) values ('".$emp_id."', '".$child_name[$i]."', '".$child_bday[$i]."') ";
    $dbcon->query($sql6);
}
```

but whenever i tried to do so, only the name of the children are saved excluding their birthdays. How can I save it using foreach if possible?

[image]

Comment: check and see wether the `$child_bday` actually contains a value, use `print_r()` for this

Comment: i tried using implode() and it displayed values.

Comment: what is the format of date in javascript, when is sended. It will be needed sended as Date, not as string?

Comment: Your code should be able to save both name and birth day. The thing causing your code ignoring the date of birth could be the date format. Make sure that date of birth is in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format before saving to db.

Comment: it's formatted already as 'y-m-d'' but it doesnt save. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will works

```
$child_name=$_POST['child'];
$count=count($child_name);

for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
  $child_bday=date('Y-d-m', strtotime($_POST['ch_DateOfBirth'][$i]));
  $sql6="INSERT into  tbl_children (Emp_ID, Ch_Name, Ch_Bdate) values ('".$emp_id."', '".$child_name[$i]."', '".$child_bday."') ";
  $dbcon->query($sql6);
}
```

Comment: But i've encountered a little problem, my form has a feature that the user can add rows , so i tried filling up the added rows and skipping the default  first three rows. when I saved it, the first three rows save a default birthdate 1970-01-01 and an empty child name, then the added rows which i filled up, save the child name but with an empty birthdate. I inspected the element using the devtools and the added rows has the same name attribute of the original rows.